Number of positive eigenvalues of a matrix sum
I was reading "A Course in Combinatorics" by Lint and Wilson and in Theorem 9.1, they use the fact that

Sum of $n$ matrices of rank 2 and trace 0 cannot have more than $n$ positive eigenvalues (positive may also be replaced by negative).

Since these matrices are symmetric and corresponding to certain quadratic forms, I understand that they must have real eigenvalues; and because rank is 2, dimension of eigenspace is 2 and it is easy to see that there must be exactly one positive and one negative eigenvalues. I get why the lemma could be plausible but I am not sure how to formally prove it. Can someone help (or suggest a reference where I can practice similar problems)?

As each summand is a symmetric matrix of rank two and trace zero, it can be written in the form of $uu^T-vv^T$ for two vectors $u$ and $v$ (of the same norm, but that is unimportant here). The sum is thus of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n(u_iu_i^T-v_iv_i^T)=\sum_{i=1}^nu_iu_i^T+\left(-\sum_{i=1}^nv_iv_i^T\right)$. Since $\sum_{i=1}^nu_iu_i^T$ is a positive semidefinite matrix of rank $\le n$, it has at most $n$ positive eigenvalues. By adding a negative semidefinite matrix $-\sum_{i=1}^nv_iv_i^T$ to it, the number of positive eigenvalues cannot increase. Hence the result.
